# How to set php data to chart.js for creating graph?

Tags: php, chart.js

my json data looks like this

```
[
    {"records":"3","month":"Jan"},
    {"records":"6","month":"Feb"},
    {"records":"2","month":"Mar"},
]
```

Now, how to show this data inside graph. I am using chart.js.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-data"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: 'set the labels here',
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "set the month name here",
          data: [set the records data here]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            }]
        },
    }
});
```

I also look many example of this. But, not able to understand. Is there an better way to achieve this? Any Example to solve this?

Comment: How are you passing in the JSON? Are you using any php framework?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know much about `php`. But since you haven't received an answer yet, I can explain the part related to Chart.js.

Given your data already present in an `array`, which I named `jsonData`, you can use the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to extract `labels` and `data` as follows:

```
labels: jsonData.map(o => o.month),
datasets: [{
  label: "Records per Month",
  data: jsonData.map(o => o.records),
```

Please have a look at your amended and runnable code below:

```js
const jsonData = [
    {"records":"3","month":"Jan"},
    {"records":"6","month":"Feb"},
    {"records":"2","month":"Mar"},
];

new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-data"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: jsonData.map(o => o.month),
    datasets: [{
      label: "Records per Month",
      data: jsonData.map(o => o.records),
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 10,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart-data" height="90"></canvas>
```